# How to pass the id name to the jquery on the dropdown change?

Tags: php, jquery, html

What I am doing is, When the user changes the dropdown then I am sending the id name to the jquery but my id is out of the `td`. How can I get it in the jQuery? I tried some code but I am getting "[object Object]."

```
   <?php $x=1; foreach($data as $row){?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <select name="Duration<?php echo $x;?>" id="Duration<?php echo $x;?>">
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="loadMe"><span id="dynamic<?php echo $x;?>"></span></div>
  </td>
  //and so on
</tr>
<?php $x++;}?>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $('[id^="Duration"]').change(function () {
  var Id=$($(this).parent().siblings('[id^="dynamic"]')[0]);
  alert(Id);
});
```

**Whole code here**

```
<?php 
$x=1;
 foreach ($MemberActivity as $activities) {
?>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="">
         <input type="hidden" name="activityID" id="activityID<?php echo $x;?>" value="<?php echo $activities->activity_name_id;?>">
            <select name="Duration<?php echo $x;?>"  class="form-control" id="Duration<?php echo $x;?>" >
              <option selected disabled >Select year</option>   
              <option value="12m">1 Year</option>
              <option value="6m">6 months</option> 
            </select>
         </div>
            </td>
         <td>
            <span id="dynamic<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $activities_name;?></span>
          </div>
        </td>
         </tr>
 <?php $x++;}?>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('[id^="Duration"]').change(function () {
   var input = $($(this).siblings('input[id^="activityID"]')[0]); // get the input element
   var activityID = input.val(); //value of the input
   var dropdownDuration = this.value;
   var results = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id^="dynamic"]').prop('id');
   alert(results);

    $.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Member_controller/checkmember",
         method:"POST",
         data:{activityID:activityID,dropdownDuration:dropdownDuration},
         success: function(msg){
           alert($(results).html(msg));
         }
       });
    });


 </script>
```

Comment: Fix first the HTML structure

Comment: Try `console.log(Id);` and you ll get your object value

Comment: If the `dynamic` span always has the name `dynamic$x` and the `Duration` select is always called `Duration$x` why not just pass the id of the `Duration` select instead as you can get `$x` from that too...

Comment: @executable, Yes, i updated my HTML code.

Comment: @Nick, dynamic name will change according to the number of records in the foreach. I mean it will be "dynamic1","dynamic2", "dynamic3" etc.

Comment: But so will `Duration` name, won't it? i.e. `Duration1`, `Duration2`, etc

Comment: @Nick, I don't need it now because that I am already getting it that jquery is haven't added. I just need when someone changes the dropdown then get the id value of dynamic.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if the `id` of `Duration` is `Duration1`, the `id` of `dynamic` will be `dynamic1`. So you can work out the `id` of `dynamic` from the `id` of `Duration` by just replacing `Duration` with `dynamic` in the `id` string.

Comment: @Nick that's true, but it's very ugly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan uglier than `var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id^="dynamic"]').prop('id');`? :-)

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your logic is that the element you want to target isn't the sibling of the parent of the `#DurationN` select. You need to fix your DOM traversal logic.

Also note that you're currently creating a jQuery object, retrieving the Element from that then turning it back in to a jQuery object again which is redundant. If you want the `id` property of the element, you can use `prop()`. Try this:

```js
$('[id^="Duration"]').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id^="dynamic"]').prop('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select name="Duration1" id="Duration1">
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="loadMe"><span id="dynamic1"></span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select name="Duration2" id="Duration2">
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="loadMe"><span id="dynamic2"></span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select name="Duration3" id="Duration3">
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="loadMe"><span id="dynamic3"></span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's also worth noting that incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern. I'd suggest using common classes instead:

```js
$('.duration').change(function() {
  var dynamic = $(this).closest('tr').find('.dynamic');
  dynamic.addClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select name="duration[]" class="duration">
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="loadMe"><span class="dynamic">foo</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select name="duration[]" class="duration">
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="loadMe"><span class="dynamic">foo</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select name="duration[]" class="duration">
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="loadMe"><span class="dynamic">foo</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, give me sometime to check.

Comment: No problem. Also, I'd suggest that you avoid using incremental `id` attributes as they are an anti-pattern. Look in to to using common classes instead.

Comment: Can you help with the class as well, So that I will try it Your answer is working for me.

Comment: Sure, I added an example for you. Note that using this pattern makes your goal of retrieving the id of the related element moot.

Comment: I thought, I am doing the best but as per your last comment about id. now I am feeling that I am stupid. I updated my code. please check whole code

Comment: What I am doing is when user select from the dropdown that value and activityID will get in the jquery and pass to the controller and ajax success it will display the status. this is my scenario but everything is in foreach

Comment: hope you understand my issue.